# Ajax Post error 500 ONLY when passing any data

Tags: ajax

The error occurs only when I pass any

data : ,

to my ajax. I tried to put it in the URL, in an array, change the name, ... nothing change the result. If I remove data, I got a proper 200 status response.

If I access directly the page, no problem, still a clean 200.

My ajax function :

```
$( "#deleteMool" ).click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    url : '/Trunk/SofastBS/mool-delete',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : 'mool=' + '4'  ,
                    dataType : 'html' ,
                    success : function(code_html, statut){

                        if (code_html == 'OK') {

                            location.reload();

                        }   
                    },
                });

        });
```

My PHP page :

```
<?php

$ID = $_POST['mool'];

// Check if user is logged in 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){

    /*.................. Empty request block ...............*/
    if ($ID != ''){

        $mool_id = delete_mool( $ID ) ;

        //On success
        if ( $mool_id == true ) {
            echo 'OK';
        }
        else{

            echo 'Une erreur est survenue.';

        }
    }
    else {

        header('Location: '.site_url());
        echo 'ID EMPTY';

    }
}
else {

    header('Location: '.site_url());
    echo 'NOT LOGGED IN';

}
```

My HEADERS :

Response header :

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2019 10:19:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Link: <http://192.168.1.95/Trunk/SofastBS/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://192.168.1.95/Trunk/SofastBS/?p=400>; rel=shortlink
Content-Length: 1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Request header :

```
POST /Trunk/SofastBS/mool-delete HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.95
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://192.168.1.95
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://192.168.1.95/Trunk/SofastBS/mool/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_censored_by_me; wp-settings-1=mfold%3Do; wp-settings-time-1=1572342088; PHPSESSID=65hhsmd6290lrei04se2tc8c93
```

In order to compare, I use the same bit of code in another web part, on another site, and work flawlessly :

Here are the headers from the working bit  :

Response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2019 10:29:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Link: <http://192.168.1.95/trunk/nagacount/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://192.168.1.95/trunk/nagacount/?p=79>; rel=shortlink
Content-Length: 2
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Request header :

```
POST /trunk/nagacount/mool-delete HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.95
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://192.168.1.95
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://192.168.1.95/trunk/nagacount/mool/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_censored_by_me; PHPSESSID=65hhsmd6290lrei04se2tc8c93
```

I'm stuck on this for a moment, I'm sure I miss something, but I can't find it out. Any hints ?

Comment: What actually you want ? Try to clear your question please.

Comment: Are you passing an id to url for delete ?

Comment: and for the data you can use it like `data: { mool: 4 },` and try to access the `mool` in your php. is this your question about? you can also pass an id in the url.

Comment: I want to pass an ID ( for future deletion, yes ) to a PHP script. But as soon as I pass an ID, I get an 500 error in response. Edit get a 200, create 200, delete → 500. I tried to pass it as you said, I tried in the URL, I tried using GET also. But each time : without data : 200, with 500.

Comment: Suppose for a while, comment out all your php code and just echo this `$ID = $_POST['mool'];` and see if it returns an id or not ? try using this method `data: { mool: 4 },` and also try to correct the order a bit, like first write `type : 'POST',` 2nd `url : '/Trunk/SofastBS/mool-delete',` 3rd `data: { mool: 4 },`